# error: passing ‘const sdf’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I am trying to execute this code. I think it's pretty straighforward but I am getting this error and I can't figure this out:

```
// THIS IS THE MAIN FILE ////////
/////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>
#include "sdf_func.hpp"
#include "single_task_func.hpp"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    sdf obj1;
    s_task cgh;
    cgh.single_task([=] {
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
            obj1.sdf_write(10);
        };
    });
    cgh.single_task([=] {
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
            obj1.sdf_write(10);
        };
    });
    return 0;
};      

// THIS IS SDF_FUNC.HPP ////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class sdf {
int done;
public:
    sdf() : done(0) {};
    void sdf_write (int size) {
        static int wr_count = 0;
        if (wr_count == size) {
            done++;
        }
        wr_count++;
        cout << wr_count;
    };
};


// THIS IS SINGLE_TASK_FUNC.HPP///////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class s_task {

struct task {

    void schedule (std::function<void(void)> f) {
        auto execution = [=] { f(); };
        std::thread thread(execution);
        thread.detach();
    };
};

task *task1;

public:
  void single_task(std::function<void(void)> F) {
    task1->schedule(F);
  }
};
```

I am trying to run 2-threads. But for some reason when I try to call the lambda-function "single_task" from the main. It gives me this error:

**error: passing ‘const sdf’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    obj1.sdf_write(10);**

Comment: You can't call `non-const` member functions on a const object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cgh.single_task([=] {
    for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
        obj1.sdf_write(10);
    };
});
```

should be:

```
cgh.single_task([=] mutable {
    for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
        obj1.sdf_write(10);
    };
});
```

From [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> mutable: allows body to modify the parameters captured by copy, and to
>   **call their non-const member functions**

As `sdf_write` is a non-const method, you have an error.

Comment: ok. I tried : **cgh.single_task ([=] () mutable {** but now I am getting very weird thing: In function `std::thread::thread<s_task::task::schedule(std::function<void ()>)::{lambda()#1}&>(s_task::task::schedule(std::function<void ()>)::{lambda()#1}&)':
top.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IRZN6s_task4task8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEEEUlvE_JEEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IRZN6s_task4task8scheduleESt8functionIFvvEEEUlvE_JEEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x30): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I want sdf_write to be **non-const** as its modifying some variables.

Comment: thanks for your help. But I am still getting the last error.